# Laurent series $\frac{e^{2z}}{(z-1)^3}$ around $z=1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Expand $$\frac{e^{2z}}{(z-1)^3}$$ around $z=1$

$$\frac{e^{2z}}{(z-1)^3}=\frac{e^{2z-2+2}}{(z-1)^3}=\frac{e^{2(z-1)+2}}{(z-1)^3}=\frac{e^{2(z-1)}e^2}{(z-1)^3}$$

Now can we say that $e^{2(z-1)}=(e^{(z-1)})^{2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{(z-1)^n}{n!})^2=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{(z-1)^{2n}}{(n!)^2})?$

Comment: Well, just as $\;a^{2x}\ne a^{x^2}\;$ (but rather $\;a^{2x}=\left(a^x\right)^2\;$ ...very different!), we get that $\;e^{2(x-1)}\neq e^{(z-1)^2}\;$ ...basic exponents mistake.

Comment: @DonAntonio Sharpe eyes, I meant $(f(x))^2$ edited the question

Comment: It is correct that $e^{2(z-1)} = (e^{z-1})^2$, but using this is complicating matters a lot. You simply use the power-series for $e^x$ directly with $x = 2(z-1)$ to get the result you are after. As for your mistake: the square of a power-series is not equal to the sum of the squares of the terms in the original series (e.g. $(a+b+c)^2 \not\equiv a^2 + b^2 + c^2$) as you seem to have assumed.

Comment: @newhere Nice, but then the mistake is in the next equality sign, where you squared only the series' general term instead of the *whole series* ...And even then, the very last series' general term has an $\;n\;$ in the wrong place: that should be an exponent.

Comment: @DonAntonio those brackets... yes it is in the exponent but as Winther said it is a mistake as it turn to $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{(z-1)^n}{n!})^2\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\frac{(z-1)^{2n}}{(n!)^2})$ and it is not equal

Comment: So my overall Laurent series is $e^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2^n(z-1)^{n-3}}{n!}$ which has $\infty$ radio of converges and a pole of order $3$ we can see it looking at the biggest negative power or from the given function $(z-1)^3$ has a pole of order $3$, expanding around any point does not change the singularity?

Comment: @newhere I think you nailed it now. Nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
e^{2(z-1)}=e^{(z-1)^{2}}
$$
is false! But you don't need that equation. Use the power series of the exponential function
$$
e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}x^k\hspace{2cm}(*1)
$$
to conclude
$$
e^{2(z-1)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}(2(z-1))^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{2^k}{k!}(z-1)^k.
$$

To "*restrictions*":

The formula $(*1)$ is given for all $x\in\mathbb C$. Hence, you can replace it by any formula and it still holds. You can even write
$$
e^{\log(z-1)}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}(\log(z-1))^k.
$$
Naturally, you have to restrict $z$ because of the logarithm but not because of the exponential function!

On the other hand, $$
\log(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}kx^k\hspace{2cm}(*2)
$$
holds just for $|x|<1$. Therefore, if you like to replace $x$ then you have the further restriction $|x|<1$. Although $z-1$ is defined for all $z\in\mathbb C$, if you like to replace $x=z-1$, you will need the further restriction $1>|x|=|z-1|$. This gives you
$$
\log(z)=\log(1+z-1)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}k(z-1)^k
$$
for $|z-1|<1$.

*(Ok, precisely the power series $(*2)$ is well defined even for some points on the boundary $|x|=1$. But it is definitely wrong for $|x|>1$. I want to point out where I thought of restrictions and simplified the details)*

Comment: So if we have a known expansion let say $e^t=\sum \frac{t^n}{n!}$ we can replace $t$ with any expression we would like? not just of the form $\pm(z-a)$ where $a\in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The power series holds for all $t\in\mathbb C$. Hence, you can replace it by an arbitrary expression without restriction.

Comment: Perhaps it should be stressed to the OP that his(her) *first* mistake is in exponents rules. Read comment below his question.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt else from $log(z-1)=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}$ at $|z|<1$ ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt you said I can just replace without restriction, but in the case of $log(z-1)$ we do have restriction

Comment: @newhere You misunderstood at which place I thought about restrictions. I added it to my answer above because it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In the last line your computations are wrong. $e^{2(z-1)}=\sum_0^{\infty }\frac {2^{n}(z-1)^{n}} {n!}$.